# Nuget Restore ignore references projects

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-pipelines, nuget-package-restore

I'm trying to migrate a .NET core library project from VS2015 to VS2017, which will cause the project.json file to be converted into a .csproj file.
Now, the project is referencing two libraries that I've created, and when build are being pushed to VSTS package manager.

When working with the project in Visual Studio I prefer to have the to referenced projects added to my solution, so I can work on the code in the same solution. At the same time I'd like the project to reference the packages, so when build on VSTS it'll pickup the packages instead.

With the project.json file, this worked fine, nuget restore (I'm using nuget restore, since dotnet restore cannot autheticate to VSTS packagemanager) would just restore the packages and I could build it.

Now with the .csproj file, the references projects are added like this:

```
<ItemGroup">
  <ProjectReference Include="myliba\src\myliba.csproj" />
  <ProjectReference Include="mylibb\src\mylibb.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

which will make 'nuget restore' try to restore packages for these projects as well.. but since these projects are in another repository, they are not (and should not) being downloaded from the repository, and 'nuget restore' fails with the error:

```
Errors in C:\a\1\s\src\mylib\mylib.csproj
    Unable to resolve 'C:\a\1\myliba\src\myliba' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1'.
    Unable to resolve 'C:\a\1\mylibb\src\mylibb.csproj' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1'.
```

How do I make nuget ignore these ProjectReferences, and make it get the libraries from the VSTS package manager instead?

**One solution:**

If I define a variable on VSTS called 'BuildSystem' and set it to VSTS, then I can check for this in my .csproj

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(BuildSystem))' == '' ">
  <ProjectReference Include="myliba\src\myliba.csproj" />
  <ProjectReference Include="mylibb\src\mylibb.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Though it means that I have to tailor all my .csproj manually, which is **not** optimal

Answer (score 0):

You are using project reference (ProjectReference) instead of package reference. You need to install the corresponding packages from VSTS package feed.

The sample project file code (project and package references):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="ClassLibraryCore2017" Version="1.0.0" /><!--package reference-->
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj" /><!--project reference-->
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

You can refer to these steps to achieve your requirement:

1. Add VSTS feed to Nuget source by calling

this command

```
nuget sources add -name [feed name] -source [your vsts feed] -username test -password [personal access token] -StorePasswordInClearText
```

2. Install packages from your VSTS feed to your project via VS 2017.
3. Add Nuget.config (in %appdata%\Nuget folder) to the source control (at the same level of solution file)
4. Check in changes
5. If you are using NuGet Installer step/task, specify NuGet.config in **Path to NuGet.Config input box**.
6. If you are using .Net Core (Preview) step/task, specify this arguments in **Arguments input box**: `--configfile ..\Config\NuGet.Config`

Comment: I have them both in my .csproj file, since I'd like to use ProjectReferences when working in VS2017 and PackageReferences when building on VSTS, but it seems to cause problems, seems like I have to choose to use either ProjectReferences or PackageReferences. So I can either choose to have a good experience in VS2017 but not being able to build on VSTS or the other way around. With project.json it worked having both....

Comment: @smolesen You need to edit project file to add corresponding references per to condition, then specify build argument.

Comment: Was hoping on a way where I didn't have to tailor my .csproj files with conditions.... would have expected it to work as smooth as in vs2015

Comment: @smolesen In my opinion, it's better to use one of them, because others may confuse if project reference source changed but not updated to package feed.

Comment: But if I use projectreferences, then my CI/CD will fail, because these projects esists in another repository. If using packagereferences it'll be a pain in the b... to be a developer, having to debug and test the code.... was working quite ok in vs2015 with project.json .....

Comment: @smolesen Adding corresponding references pre to condition is the better way, could not find another better way.